# Equivalence relation - reflexity

Tags: equivalence-relations

I need to prove that relation is an equivalence relation. Equivalence relation means it satisfies reflexity, symmetry, and transitivity.

If I was given an set of numbers *S=(-1,1)* and for example for *-(1/2)* relation is not reflexive, but for *1/2* it is reflexive. Does that mean that in the end relation is not reflexive, because it's not reflexive for all numbers from that set?

Thank you!

Comment: Reflexivity means that $aRa$ for **all** $a\in S$.

Comment: So, in this case it's not reflexive. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, reflexivity has to hold for all elements of the set of concern. More precisely, let $R$ be a relation on $S$. Then, for all $s \in S$, we must have $(s,s) \in R$ (or $sRs$ depending on your notation of preference). We might write this as $\forall s \in S, (s,s) \in R$.

It only takes a single counterexample to bring the entire thing toppling down as a result. It has to hold for literally everything in $S$ or it's not reflexive.